# PySpark how to join 2 DataFrames efficiently with non-matching keys

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two Dataframes of different sizes:
df1 (22 million rows), contains Latitude, Longitude, Date, Event
df2 (100K rows), contains Latitude, Longitude, Date, temperature

For each row in df1, I'd like to find the closest matching location (defined by Euclidean Distance) for that date in table df2 (table df2 has all possible dates, while table df1 does not).

df1

```
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Latitude | Longitude |   Date   |   Event    |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
|       10 |        10 | 11/10/20 | Water Polo |
|       20 |        20 | 11/22/19 | Cricket    |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

df2:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
| Latitude | Longitude |   Date   | Weather |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
|       20 |        20 | 11/10/20 |      90 |
|       12 |        12 | 11/10/20 |      80 |
|       10 |        10 | 11/22/19 |      34 |
|       18 |        18 | 11/22/19 |      45 |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+
| Latitude | Longitude |   Date   | Weather |   Event    |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+
|       10 |        10 | 11/10/20 |      80 | Water Polo |
|       20 |        20 | 11/22/19 |      45 | Cricket    |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+
```

I'm pretty new to PySpark and not sure how to write this query in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you could join on **`Date`**, then compute your **`Distance`** using pyspark inbuilt functions **`sqrt, pow`** , and then take a **`window partitioned by Date`** to calculate **`minimum distance per date(min_Distance)`**, and then **`filter`** on that.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("Date")

df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("Latitude","Latitude1")\
            .withColumnRenamed("Longitude","Longitude1"),['Date'])\
   .withColumn("Distance",F.sqrt(F.pow(F.col("Latitude")-F.col("Latitude1"),2)+\
                                 F.pow(F.col("Longitude")-F.col("Longitude1"),2)))\
   .withColumn("min_Distance", F.min("Distance").over(w))\
   .filter('Distance=min_Distance')\
   .select("Latitude","Longitude","Date","Weather","Event").show()

#+--------+---------+--------+-------+----------+
#|Latitude|Longitude|    Date|Weather|     Event|
#+--------+---------+--------+-------+----------+
#|      10|       10|11/10/20|     80|Water Polo|
#|      20|       20|11/22/19|     45|   Cricket|
#+--------+---------+--------+-------+----------+
```